# Change Image in Select options

Tags: javascript, html, image

I want to build the following structure: load a image next to a select/options and when change option, change the image too. Html:

```
<label for="Estilo"> Arte Marcial:</label>
<select name="Estilo" id="estilo">
    <option value=""> </option>
    <option value="Taekwondo" id="taekwondo">Taekwondo</option>
    <option value="Boxe" id="boxe">Boxe</option>
    <option value="Karate" id ="karate">Karate</option>
</select>
<img src="/imgs/mestra.png" class="imagem__muda">
```

I already tried different solutions and none of them worked, but i think i am close to a solution on the following code:

```
const selecionado = document.querySelector('#estilo')

selecionado.addEventListener('onChange',()=>{

  if (selecionado.value == "Boxe"){
    foto.src= '/imgs/boxe.png'
  }

  
})
```

Also, is this the best option to resolve my problem? I already search for other questions and answers but they always uses buttons, so  i don´t think they are applicable.

Comment: There is no event called `onChange`, it is just `change`.

Comment: Is your code running (i.e. is the event callback function being called in your example)? If not, try using the 'change' event rather than 'onChange'

Comment: And where is `foto` supposed to come from?

Comment: i forgot the foto reference when copied and pasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues in your code:

1. You have no references of *foto*.
2. As *onChange* is an HTML attribute, you should use *change* instead of *onChange* when using that in JavaScript.

```js
const selecionado = document.querySelector('#estilo');
var foto =  document.querySelector('.imagem__muda');
selecionado.addEventListener('change', ()=>{
  if (selecionado.value == "Boxe"){    
    foto.src = '/imgs/boxe.png'; 
  }
});
```

```html
<label for="Estilo"> Arte Marcial:</label>
<select name="Estilo" id="estilo">
    <option value=""> </option>
    <option value="Taekwondo" id="taekwondo">Taekwondo</option>
    <option value="Boxe" id="boxe">Boxe</option>
    <option value="Karate" id ="karate">Karate</option>
</select>
<img src="/imgs/mestra.png" class="imagem__muda">
```